# Train and accept the added Questions in QnA programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to add questions to existing questions in my knowledge base in `QnA Maker` like this:

```cs
 public async static void CallTrain(string host, FeedbackRecords feedbackRecords, string kbId, string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
         var uri = host + "/knowledgebases/" + kbId + "/train/";

         using (var client = new HttpClient())
         {
             using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
             {
                 request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                 request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
                 request.Content = new 
                       StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(feedbackRecords), 
                       Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "EndpointKey " + key);

                 var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                 await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             }
         }
     }
```

FeedbackRecords sample:

```
[
  {
    "userId":"xxx",
    "userQuestion":"what is your name",
    "qnaId":1
  }
]
```

Everything works fine and the questions were added, BUT I must accept the added questions in the QnA Maker Portal first to see them.

So my question is how to accept all the questions progrmatically and retrain the knowledge base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is possible using the [QnA Maker API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff).

*Edit*

This has been confirmed as per the [OPs comment below](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fd9dc1c-e62c-4c74-aaeb-f59f3996b2fa/train-and-accept-the-added-questions-in-qna-programmatically?forum=AzureCognitiveService) it has been confirmed that this is not currently available but it is on the development backlog so may be available at the link I provided above in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's unfortunately not available, MS team has added it to their backlog :)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fd9dc1c-e62c-4c74-aaeb-f59f3996b2fa/train-and-accept-the-added-questions-in-qna-programmatically?forum=AzureCognitiveService

Comment: Although accepting active learning suggestions programmatically is not available yet, you can check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/172) which sends all the updates at once via Update Knowledgebase API.